# No function output

Tags: python

trying to run a simple calculator in python. There is no error codes that pop up, yet there is no output. If anyone can help that would be great

Code below

```
def BMR_calc(gender, weight, height, age):
  if gender == 0:
      return (66.47 +(6.24*weight)+(12.7*height)-(6.76*age))
  elif gender == 1:
      return ((4.54*weight)+ (15.88*height)-(5*age)-161)

aBMR = BMR_calc(0, 250, 65, 30)
```

Comment: Add and `else` too.

Comment: There is no output because you did not `print` anything.  Perhaps you meant to add `print(aBMR)`.

Comment: There's no output because the code doesn't generate any output. Add a `print(aBMR)` to it.

Comment: And why not use 'm' and 'f' for gender?  There's no need to use magic numbers like 0 and 1 that have no meaning.

Comment: Just simply add print() command if you want to see the result as output.

Answer (score 1):

Just like what @Tim Roberts and @DrakeLiam said. Add a print statement at the end!

```
    def BMR_calc(gender, weight, height, age):
        if gender == 0:
            return (66.47 +(6.24*weight)+(12.7*height)-(6.76*age))
        elif gender == 1:
            return ((4.54*weight)+ (15.88*height)-(5*age)-161)

    aBMR = BMR_calc(0, 250, 65, 30)
    print(aBMR)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result for variable aBMR

You must print it to see the result

```
print(BMR_calc(0, 250, 65, 30))
```

[image]